# Toggle visibility of styles in quick select menu

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for a way to edit the styles, which are shown in the Word "styles quick select menu" with VBA.

In german it's "Formatvorlagenkatalog":
[image]

I plan on including two buttons to a menu tab to switch between two sets of styles.
I want to empty the "styles quick select menu" and add styles with a specific suffix. Hopefully this won't be a problem once I get a grip on the "styles quick select menu" - object.

Or maybe there's a attribute to the style itself.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.style.quickstyle

Comment: Styles("Heading 3").QuickStyles = True    Styles("Heading 1").Quickstyles = False

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you get to control the quick styles menu by setting the Attribute "Style.QuickStyle" on the Style object itself.

Here's my code to trigger the wanted changes to the quick styles menu:

```
Sub hideUnhideFormatTemplates(boolUnhide As Boolean, suffix As String)
   For Each formatTemplate In ActiveDocument.Styles
       If Right$(formatTemplate.NameLocal, 3) = suffix Then formatTemplate.QuickStyle = boolUnhide
   Next
End Sub
```